# Jquery selecting problem

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Okay, so i have:

```
<div class="catergory">
<div class="title">CATEGORY TITLE</div>
<div class="listing">
CODE FOR LISTINGS
</div>
</div>
```

What i am trying to do, is have it so when you click the CATEGORY TITLE, the LISTINGS div slides down, My problem is, is how do i select that div when i have put a click event on CATEGORY TITLE

My JQuery code is:

```
$('.title').click(function(){

$('.category > .listings',this).toggleSlide('slow');


});
```

Now, I know the problem is something with my way of selecting the correct element..

any ideas?

Thanks
Neil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$('.title').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.listing').slideToggle('slow');
});

Comment: "$(this).next(".listings").toggleSlide is not a function" comes up in firebug and nothing happens?

Comment: @nmyster `toggleSlide()` is not a jQuery method.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.title').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.listing').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

The method is also [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/), not `toggleSlide()`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/MydeC/).

Comment: yeah i got that, mistake when at writing :)

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery method is [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) not toggleSlide.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the code in $(document).ready() function as the Jquery code can be executed only after jquery is loaded..

Comment: got that, the code i put is just the snippet relevant to my problem